# How to multiply 2 OpenCV mats using a GPU

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

In OpenCV, I can multiply an RGB 1920 x 1080 mat by a 3 x 3 Mat to change the color composition of my source Mat. Once my source mat is properly shaped, I can use the '*' operator to perform the multiplication. This operator is not available when using a cv::gpu::GpuMat.

My question is how would I format my input source Mat to use cv::gpu::gemm?Can I even use cv::gpu::gemm?

This is the only call that performs matrix multiplication in the OpenCV library from what I can tell. cv::gpu::gemm wants to see a CV_32FC1 , CV_64FC1 type Mat. The type I normally use with the CPU is CV_32FC3.

```
//sourceMat is CV_32FC3 1920 x 1080 Mat
Mat sourceMat = matFromBuffer(data->bufferA, data->widthA, data->heightA);

//This is the color Matrix
float matrix[3][3] = {{1.057311, -0.204043, 0.055648},
{ 0.041556, 1.875992, -0.969256},
{-0.498535,-1.537150, 3.240479}};

Mat colorMatrixMat = Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC1, matrix).t();

//Color Correct the Mat
Mat linearSourceMat = sourceMat.reshape(1, 1080*1920);
Mat multipliedMatrix = linearSourceMat * colorMatrixMat;
Mat recoloredMat = multipliedMatrix.reshape(3, 1080);
```

Update:
As a test, I created the test routine:

```
static int gpuTest(){

    float matrix[9] = {1.057311, -0.204043, 0.055648, 0.041556, 1.875992, -0.969256, -0.498535,-1.537150, 3.240479};
    Mat matrixMat = Mat(1, 9, CV_32FC1, matrix).t();
    cv::gpu::GpuMat gpuMatrixMat;
    gpuMatrixMat.upload(matrixMat);

    float matrixDest[9] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    Mat matrixDestMat = Mat(1, 9, CV_32FC1, matrixDest).t();
    cv::gpu::GpuMat destMatrixMat;
    destMatrixMat.upload(matrixDestMat);

    cv::gpu::GpuMat nextMat;
    cv::gpu::gemm(gpuMatrixMat, destMatrixMat, 1, cv::gpu::GpuMat(), 0, nextMat);

    return 0;
};
```

and the error I receive is:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src1Size.width == src2Size.height) in gemm, file /Users/myuser/opencv-2.4.12/modules/gpu/src/arithm.cpp, line 109
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/myuser/opencv-2.4.12/modules/gpu/src/arithm.cpp:109: error: (-215) src1Size.width == src2Size.height in function gemm
```

Now how can the src1Size.width be equal to src2Size.height? The width and height are different.

Comment: Wouldn't `sourceMat.reshape(1, 1080*1920);` reduce the channels to 1, therefore making `linearSourceMat` have type `CV_32FC1`? Your `colorMatrixMat` is also `CV_32FC1`. So it seems to me that gemm should work with your data as is.

Comment: My mat is CV_32FC3, so it is 1080 columns by 1920 rows of 3 elements RGB. When I reshape it to (1, 1080*1920). I am creating 1 column and  1080*1920 rows of RGB values.

Comment: From what I read in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=reshape#Mat%20Mat::reshape%28int%20cn,%20int%20rows%29%20const) the first argument to `Mat::reshape` is _the number of channels_. According to my understanding, this would mean you're creating a single channel matrix with 1080*1920 rows and 3 columns. Since you're multiplying by a 3x3 matrix, this has to be true (according to how matrix multiplication is defined). Check the type in the debugger...

Comment: Let me see if I can try it out locally. I'm not certain I've got my copy of OpenCV built with the GPU support enabled.

Comment: I've confirmed my assumptions about the type of the matrix. Can't get the gpu version working at this point, haven't really used that before and it's getting a bit late.

Comment: Yes, I should have been clearer. 3 column of 1920*1080. I'll open up a bounty in a couple of days. thanks for looking at it. Am interested to see what you make of the gpu version.

Comment: Ok, I did some research and testing. Not entirely successful in verifying it, as so far i haven't been able to get hold of usable binaries that would have everything built in. Let me know if this gets you anywhere. One thought tho -- unless you're going to do some more work on those images on the GPU, the overhead in getting the data to/from GPU may be too large.

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate this. Fortunately, the GPU is much, much faster than the CPU. I don't need to get the data back off of the GPU so I can suffer though the upload slowdown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a minimum working example using OpenCV 3.1.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>

int main()
{ 
    cv::Mat sourceMat = cv::Mat::ones(1080, 1920, CV_32FC3);

    //This is the color Matrix
    float matrix[3][3] = {
        { 1.057311, -0.204043, 0.055648 }
        , { 0.041556, 1.875992, -0.969256 }
        , { -0.498535, -1.537150, 3.240479 }
        };

    cv::Mat colorMatrixMat = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC1, matrix).t();

    cv::Mat linearSourceMat = sourceMat.reshape(1, 1080 * 1920);
    cv::Mat multipliedMatrix = linearSourceMat * colorMatrixMat;

    try {
        cv::Mat dummy, gpuMultipliedMatrix;

        // Regular gemm
        cv::gemm(linearSourceMat, colorMatrixMat, 1.0, dummy, 0.0, gpuMultipliedMatrix);
        // CUDA gemm
        // cv::cuda::gemm(linearSourceMat, colorMatrixMat, 1.0, dummy, 0.0, gpuMultipliedMatrix);

        std::cout << (cv::countNonZero(multipliedMatrix != gpuMultipliedMatrix) == 0);
    } catch (cv::Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Note that when the beta parameter to `gemm(...)` is zero, the third input matrix is ignored (based on the code).

Unfortunately I don't have a build of OpenCV compiled with CUBLAS available to try it, but it should work.

---

*Following is somewhat speculative...*

To make this work with OpenCV 2.4, you will need to add a little bit more. Before calling `gemm(...)`, you need to create `GpuMat` objects and upload the data.

```
cv::gpu::GpuMat gpuLinSrc, gpuColorMat, dummy, gpuResult;
gpuLinSrc.upload(linearSourceMat);
gpuColorMat.upload(colorMatrixMat);
```

Then...

```
cv::gpu::gemm(gpuLinSrc, gpuColorMat, 1.0, cv::gpu::GpuMat(), 0.0, gpuResult);
```

and finally download the data back from the GPU.

```
cv::Mat resultFromGPU;
gpuResult.download(resultFromGPU);
```

---

## Update

Here's a more detailed example to show you what's happening:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

// ============================================================================

// Make a 3 channel test image with 5 rows and 4 columns
cv::Mat make_image()
{
    std::vector<float> v(5 * 4);
    std::iota(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 1.0f); // Fill with 1..20
    cv::Mat seq(5, 4, CV_32FC1, v.data()); // 5 rows, 4 columns, 1 channel

    // Create 3 channels, each with different offset, so we can tell them apart
    cv::Mat chans[3] = {
        seq, seq + 100, seq + 200
    };

    cv::Mat merged;
    cv::merge(chans, 3, merged); // 5 rows, 4 columns, 3 channels

    return merged;
}

// Make a transposed color correction matrix.
cv::Mat make_color_mat()
{
    float color_in[3][3] = {
        { 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f } // Coefficients for channel 0
        , { 0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f } // Coefficients for channel 1
        , { 0.7f, 0.8f, 0.9f } // Coefficients for channel 2
    };

    return cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC1, color_in).t();
}

void print_mat(cv::Mat m, std::string const& label)
{
    std::cout << label << ":\n  size=" << m.size()
        << "\n  channels=" << m.channels()
        << "\n" << m << "\n" << std::endl;
}

// Perform matrix multiplication to obtain result point (r,c)
float mm_at(cv::Mat a, cv::Mat b, int r, int c)
{
    return a.at<float>(r, 0) * b.at<float>(0, c)
        + a.at<float>(r, 1) * b.at<float>(1, c)
        + a.at<float>(r, 2) * b.at<float>(2, c);
}

// Perform matrix multiplication to obtain result row r
cv::Vec3f mm_test(cv::Mat a, cv::Mat b, int r)
{
    return cv::Vec3f(
        mm_at(a, b, r, 0)
        , mm_at(a, b, r, 1)
        , mm_at(a, b, r, 2)
        );
}

// ============================================================================

int main()
{ 
    try {
        // Step 1
        cv::Mat source_image(make_image());
        print_mat(source_image, "source_image");
        std::cout << "source pixel at (0,0): " << source_image.at<cv::Vec3f>(0, 0) << "\n\n";

        // Step 2
        cv::Mat color_mat(make_color_mat());
        print_mat(color_mat, "color_mat");

        // Step 3
        // Reshape the source matrix to obtain a matrix:
        // * with only one channel (CV_32FC1)
        // * where each row corresponds to a single pixel from source
        // * where each column corresponds to a single channel from source
        cv::Mat reshaped_image(source_image.reshape(1, source_image.rows * source_image.cols));
        print_mat(reshaped_image, "reshaped_image");

        // Step 4
        cv::Mat corrected_image;
        // corrected_image = 1.0 * reshaped_image * color_mat
        cv::gemm(reshaped_image, color_mat, 1.0, cv::Mat(), 0.0, corrected_image);
        print_mat(corrected_image, "corrected_image");

        // Step 5
        // Reshape back to the original format
        cv::Mat result_image(corrected_image.reshape(3, source_image.rows));
        print_mat(result_image, "result_image");
        std::cout << "result pixel at (0,0): " << result_image.at<cv::Vec3f>(0, 0) << "\n\n";

        // Step 6
        // Calculate one pixel manually...
        std::cout << "check pixel (0,0): " << mm_test(reshaped_image, color_mat, 0) << "\n\n";
    } catch (cv::Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what();
        return -1;
    }
}

// ============================================================================
```

### Step 1

First we create a small test input image:

- The image contains 3 channels of float values, i.e. the data type is `CV_32FC3`. Let's treat the channels as *red*, *green*, *blue* in that order.
- The image contains 5 rows of pixels.
- The image contains 4 columns of pixels.
- Values in each channel are sequential, `green = red + 100` and `blue = red + 200`.

```
source_image:
  size=[4 x 5]
  channels=3
[1, 101, 201, 2, 102, 202, 3, 103, 203, 4, 104, 204;
 5, 105, 205, 6, 106, 206, 7, 107, 207, 8, 108, 208;
 9, 109, 209, 10, 110, 210, 11, 111, 211, 12, 112, 212;
 13, 113, 213, 14, 114, 214, 15, 115, 215, 16, 116, 216;
 17, 117, 217, 18, 118, 218, 19, 119, 219, 20, 120, 220]
```

We can print out a single pixel, to make the structure clearer:

```
source pixel at (0,0): [1, 101, 201]
```

### Step 2

Create a sample colour correction matrix (transposed) such that:

- First column contains coefficients used to determine the *red* value
- Second column contains coefficients used to determine the *green* value
- Third column contains coefficients used to determine the *blue* value

```
color_mat:
  size=[3 x 3]
  channels=1
[0.1, 0.40000001, 0.69999999;
 0.2, 0.5, 0.80000001;
 0.30000001, 0.60000002, 0.89999998]
```

### Sidenote: Color Correction Algorithm

We want to transform source pixel **S** to pixel **T** using coefficients **C**

```
S = [ sr, sg, sb ]
T = [ tr, tg, tb ]
C = [ cr1, cr2, cr3;
      cg1, cg2, cg3;
      cb1, cb2, cb3]
```

Such that

```
Tr = cr1 * sr + cr2 * sg + cr3 * sb
Tg = cg1 * sr + cg2 * sg + cg3 * sb
Tb = cb1 * sr + cb2 * sg + cb3 * sb
```

Which can be represented by the following matrix expression

```
T = S * C_transpose
```

### Step 3

In order to be able to use the above algorithm, we first need to reshape our image into a matrix that:

- Contains a single channel, so that value at each point is just a float
- Has one pixel per row.
- Has 3 columns representing *red*, *green*, *blue*

In this shape, matrix multiplication will mean that each pixel/row from input gets multiplied by the coefficient matrix to determine one pixel/row in the output.

The reshaped matrix looks as follows:

```
reshaped_image:
  size=[3 x 20]
  channels=1
[1, 101, 201;
 2, 102, 202;
 3, 103, 203;
 4, 104, 204;
 5, 105, 205;
 6, 106, 206;
 7, 107, 207;
 8, 108, 208;
 9, 109, 209;
 10, 110, 210;
 11, 111, 211;
 12, 112, 212;
 13, 113, 213;
 14, 114, 214;
 15, 115, 215;
 16, 116, 216;
 17, 117, 217;
 18, 118, 218;
 19, 119, 219;
 20, 120, 220]
```

### Step 4

We perform the multiplication, for example using `gemm`, to get the following matrix:

```
corrected_image:
  size=[3 x 20]
  channels=1
[80.600006, 171.5, 262.39999;
 81.200005, 173, 264.79999;
 81.800003, 174.5, 267.20001;
 82.400002, 176, 269.60001;
 83, 177.5, 272;
 83.600006, 179, 274.39999;
 84.200005, 180.5, 276.79999;
 84.800003, 182, 279.20001;
 85.400002, 183.5, 281.60001;
 86, 185, 284;
 86.600006, 186.5, 286.39999;
 87.200005, 188, 288.79999;
 87.800003, 189.5, 291.20001;
 88.400009, 191, 293.60001;
 89, 192.5, 296;
 89.600006, 194, 298.39999;
 90.200005, 195.50002, 300.79999;
 90.800003, 197, 303.20001;
 91.400009, 198.5, 305.60001;
 92, 200, 308]
```

### Step 5

Now we can reshape the image back to the original shape. The result is

```
result_image:
  size=[4 x 5]
  channels=3
[80.600006, 171.5, 262.39999, 81.200005, 173, 264.79999, 81.800003, 174.5, 267.20001, 82.400002, 176, 269.60001;
 83, 177.5, 272, 83.600006, 179, 274.39999, 84.200005, 180.5, 276.79999, 84.800003, 182, 279.20001;
 85.400002, 183.5, 281.60001, 86, 185, 284, 86.600006, 186.5, 286.39999, 87.200005, 188, 288.79999;
 87.800003, 189.5, 291.20001, 88.400009, 191, 293.60001, 89, 192.5, 296, 89.600006, 194, 298.39999;
 90.200005, 195.50002, 300.79999, 90.800003, 197, 303.20001, 91.400009, 198.5, 305.60001, 92, 200, 308]
```

Let's have a look at one pixel from the result:

```
result pixel at (0,0): [80.6, 171.5, 262.4]
```

### Step 6

Now we can double check our result by performing the appropriate calculations manually (functions `mm_test` and `mm_at`).

```
check pixel (0,0): [80.6, 171.5, 262.4]
```

Comment: I created a test routine at http://pastebin.com/Td1MKfWr. I multiply a 1x9  CV_32F1 against a 9x1 CV_32F1 which produces a 9x9 CV_32F1. This code works, but the matrix multiplication produces a larger mat. In my CPU matrix multiplication code, I multiply a CV_32F3 1920X1080 Mat against a CV_32F1 3X3 Mat which performs the color correction and doesn't enlarge my resultant Mat. I guess my question comes down to - how is gemm distinct from the Mat operator '*'?

Comment: When you create the two input matrices there, you transpose them (the `.t()`). So you actually have 9x1 multiplied by 1x9 and that produces a 9x9 result.

Comment: Good point. but even if I don't transpose them, it doesn't make a difference. It would still be a 9X9 Mat

Comment: I don't believe that's correct. When multiplying matrix of size `AxB` with matrix size `BxC` you get result size `AxC`. So you should either get a 1x1 (1x9 * 9x1) or 9x9 (9x1 * 1x9). See http://pastebin.com/66HawPHr

Comment: In your case (based on what i explained earlier), due to the reshaping you've done, the multiplication is 2073600x3 matrix * 3x3 matrix giving 2073600x3 matrix as result.

Comment: So to that point, if gemm only wants a CV_32FC1 Mat, I would need to reshape my mat which is CV_32FC3 1080 X 1920 to CV32FC1 1 X (3 x 1080 x 1920)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107243/discussion-between-dan-masek-and-blackirishman).